Which of dark or light theme is my WinUI application currently using?
I'm looking for a way to check which theme is my WinUI application currently using?
Users can select the theme they want from the settings as: dark, light or default, but in the end the app is either dark or light.

You can create a helper class:
public static class ThemeHelpers
{
    public static ElementTheme GetTheme(this FrameworkElement element)
        => element.RequestedTheme switch
        {
            ElementTheme.Default => ToElementTheme(Application.Current.RequestedTheme),
            _ => element.RequestedTheme,
        };

    public static ElementTheme ToElementTheme(ApplicationTheme applicationTheme)
        => applicationTheme is ApplicationTheme.Light
            ? ElementTheme.Light
            : ElementTheme.Dark;

    public static bool IsLightTheme(this FrameworkElement element)
    => element.GetTheme() is ElementTheme.Light;

    public static bool IsDarkTheme(this FrameworkElement element)
        => element.GetTheme() is ElementTheme.Dark;
}

and use it on Pages or FrameworkElements like this:
iColor = this.IsDark() ? Colors.Black : Colors.Light;


Say if you want to pick a color contrasting with your app current theme it could look like that:
if (ActualTheme == ElementTheme.Default)
{
    // Currently using system default so check which it is to choose our color
    iColor = Application.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Light ? Colors.Black : Colors.White;
}
else
{
    // Not using system default theme so choose our color according to our theme override
    iColor = ActualTheme == ElementTheme.Light ? Colors.Black : Colors.White;
}

Where ActualTheme is a method of FrameworkElement so you could run that code from any of your Pages for instance.
